# Store two values in a select form element separately

Tags: html, forms

Does there exist a way to store two separate values in a select form element? For instance

```
<select>
   <option value="">A + B</option>
</select>
```

I would like to store values A and B separately, but select them both with one option.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish or give an example scenario?

Comment: @Mazzy Not with only HTML, no. You might be able to use JavaScript to select part of the option before a specific character (like **+**), store it, and then select part of the option *after* that character, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can add two options:

```
 <option value="a">A</option>
 <option value="b">B</option>
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use a multiple select instead:

```
<select name="yourChoices[ ]" multiple>
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Users are able to choose more than one option.

Here is an example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple